# IBOutlet is nil inside custom UIView (Using STORYBOARD)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, storyboard, iboutlet

I have a custom `UIView` class. Inside it I have declared an  `IBOutlet` property for `UIImageView`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingItem : UIView{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;

@end
```

Now i am using storyboard. There is a viewcontroller. I dragged `UIView` to viewcontroller. I dragged one `UIImageView` as a subview of above `UIView`. I set the "SettingItem" class to `UIView` from storyboard. I connected the outlet to myImage by normal dragging from outlets of `SettingItem` from utilities window.

---

### `SettingItem` implementation

```
#import "SettingItem.h"

@implementation SettingItem

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) baseInit{
    NSLog(@"myImage %@"self.myImage);
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Now my problem is `myImage` is always `nil`, above `NSLog` just print `(null)` for the outlet. I checked the view in storyboard and checked its outlet reference and its pointing to `myImage`. I am missing something. I googled for the help but couldn't find any solution.

Can you please point out what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you declare the IBOutlet property as `strong` instead of `weak`? Is it because it's a property of the `UIView` itself so it is the only owner of the property?  Thanks

Comment: @PabloA. Yes It is the only owner.  Also Xcode IB of that time used to put strong to outlets by default, i think. So you would have to reedit to weak or take care of it with the situation in hand.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Override awakeFromNib in your view - this is the first lifecycle method to be called after the IBOutlets have been assigned and is the right place for your code.

Comment: Short: this is the only correct answer here, others should be wrapped into lead cover and sent to space.
Long: Oh, how I hope when I'm going to ask anything on SO, there would be somebody like @Oly to provide the only reasonable and correct answer. Other answers are so rubbish, that it just demonstrates absence of required knowledge. Please, be more like Oly and less like the rest in this thread.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii You've just cheered up my day, I've just returned to work after a horrible accident last year and needed some encouragement ;-)

Comment: In awakefromNib, it is still getting null values, i have searched many things on stackoverflow, and answer i got at many links is that content is lazy loaded, so in awakefromnib, you can have iboutlets values null

Answer (score 4):

initialize them in awakeFromNib:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //init code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same problem and the solution is really easy:

You're accessing `myImage` to soon - that's it.

Withing `-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{` and `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` the `UIView` is not already drawed. So myImage is not initalized yet.

You can test it if you add a `UIButton` and an `IBAction` and do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",myImage);
}
```

And you'll see how `myImage` is not `nil` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, but I finally figured out what was wrong - It was a difference in the idiom between XIB files and Storyboards.

In all the tutorials that I had seen with Xib files, if I had a UITableViewController create a DetailViewController to let me edit the content of the items in the table, then the tableViewController created an instance of the DVC once when it first revealed it, but then reused that same DVC instance whenever it needed to edit another item on the list.

With storyboards, it appears that the a view that is revealed by a table view is typically created new each time the table view calls it up (and it doesn't call up the version of init that is in the UIViewController template). As a previous answer stated, you have to wait until "ViewDidLoad" to access any of the controls, even if you have shown this view before.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the setter for properties, that way you can do what you need when it's actually populated?

```
@IBOutlet weak var xxx:UIKitClass! {
  didSet { 
    outletSetup() 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Call `[self baseInit]` inside `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. `myImage` should have a value there.

```
#import "SettingItem.h"

@implementation SettingItem

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self baseInit];
}

- (void) baseInit{
    NSLog(@"myImage %@"self.myImage);
}
```

Comment: viewWillAppear doesn't belong to UIView, is it ? Its in UIViewController.

Answer (score -6):

in your .h file you need to replace your code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingItem : UIView{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;

@end
```

With this code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingItem : UIView{

  IBOutlet UIImageView*myImage;

}

@end
```

You are not actually telling Xcode what myImage is, you are just making it a strong, nonatomic property

Comment: then how am i supposed to connect outlet to it from storyboard since property is not visible anymore ?

Comment: if you click on the status bar of the view and then go to the connections inspector then link it

Comment: Thanks but still getting null

Comment: @OnkaPlonka You're wrong. The `IBOutlet` in the `@property`-declaration does mean, it's available in the `UIStoryBoard`. You shouldn't use `@interface Class : SuperClass { IBOutlet ... }` anymore.

Comment: @OnkaPlonka Of course it's not wrong but it's not the solution.

Comment: Those two declarations are, firstly, equivalent with respect to their ivar storage (modulo the ivar's name: in the first one, the property will be auto-synthesized to `_myImage`, whereas the second one is named `myImage`), but second and more importantly, this has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: But you are not answering his question.