# IOS Collection View load Image from custom cell class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to implement collectionView with custom collectionViewCell class. Below code works fine, where the image is loading from Collection view  class itself.

**customCollectionView.m**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";        
    MyCell *cell =  (MyCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];        
    UIImage *Img = [UIImage imageNamed:[Images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.myImageView.image = Img;
    cell.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    return cell;
}
```

**MyCell.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Whereas when I moved the image loading part to custom `CollectionViewCell` class `MyCell` the `image` is not displaying.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
         UIImage *Img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon.png"];
         _myImageView.image = Img;

    }
    return self;
}
```

My purpose is to loading different image from MyCell class in specific time interval and display on each cell.

Comment: first check with a break point wheter the iboulet in nil. then see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089410/iboutlet-is-nil-inside-custom-uiview-using-storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement `prepareForReuse` method of `UICollectionViewCell` inside your customCell `MyCell`

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {

    _myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon.png"];
}
```

Try `awakeFromNib` and remove `prepareForReuse`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    _myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon.png"];
}
```

Comment: Still no change, the image is not loading.

Comment: Yes, and it's displaying image from collectionView custom class.

Comment: I set a break point `prepareForReuse()` and it's not get called.