# swift nil when setting the value of text field

Tags: ios, swift2

this is my prepare for segue code

```
switch segue.identifier! {
        case SegueIdentifiers.SecondUIViewController.rawValue:
            print("\(SegueIdentifiers.SecondUIViewController.rawValue)")
            let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController

            secondViewController!.resultTextField.text = "asdfasdf"
            //break
        default:
            print("nothing sweetheart")
            break
        }
```

i got nil exception on this line

```
secondViewController!.resultTextField.text = "asdfasdf"
```

why ? the text field already there

this is the second view controller

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: did you hook your text field up to the outlet in IB?

Comment: Have you debugged, setting a breakpoint and examine values? Is `secondViewController` nil or `resultTextField` nil? At least half of developing code is debugging in some form, gotta get that skill.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBOutlet properties does not update when using prepareForSegue method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033924/iboutlet-properties-does-not-update-when-using-prepareforsegue-method)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766432/why-cant-this-view-controller-set-the-text-fields-of-the-next-view-controller?lq=1

Comment: is the destination view loaded on prepare for segue method? may be use a string aux var, set it from prepare segue and on your destination viewDidLoad method `resultTextField.text = aux`

Answer (score 3):

Your `outlets` are not set until `viewDidLoad`. Before that they are all `nil`. This is why they are optionals. Thus when you try to access them from `prepareForSegue` they are still `nil`.

I recommend you add a new property to your view controller, and set that from `prepareForSegue`. Later when your `outlets` are set you can update your text field.

```
// in prepareForSegue
let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController
secondViewController!.resultText = "asdfasdf"
```

And then in your view controller

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var resultText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            resultTextField?.text = text
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var resultTextField: UITextField! {
        // Will be set once in viewDidLoad.
        // Whenever that happens update text.
        didSet {
            resultTextField.text = resultText
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can modify your text field from the `resultText` property even before the `outlets` are set, and they will be updated when set thanks to the `didSet` property observer.