# Where to initialize UILabel?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Somewhere in my storyboard I have ViewController(ReadingViewController), which I am instantiating the following way:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:NULL];
ReadingViewController *viewController = (ReadingViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SB_RDVC"];
viewController.infoLabel.text = @"test";
```

That VC has some label outlets created in storyboard. When I try to initialize the label right after instantiation, it failed - label value is same as I set in storyboard.

As workaround I made a string property in VC, then just assigning @"test" to that variable. In viewDidLoad of `ReadingViewController` I just `self.infoLabel.text = self.uglyProperty`.

This seems ugly to me, is there a better way to assign outlet label right after instantiation?

Comment: explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033924/iboutlet-properties-does-not-update-when-using-prepareforsegue-method

Comment: ah, so the way I am handling it now is the only valid...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason why your text is the same as before is because your view has not loaded yet - set a breakpoint in viewDidLoad method of your VC and see if that gets called before or after you assign your label.

You could write a protocol and make your class a delegate of ReadingViewController, so that you could receive a callback when viewDidLoad is called, although I'm not sure that's a simpler solution than creating a property for the infoLabel text.

Comment: I'll stick with property :)