# setting properties in the detail view from prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a Master/Detail application with xCode and changed very little about it. In prepareForSegue in the MasterViewController, I added this to try to put some text in a label in the detail view controller

```
MMDetailViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
detailVC.testdetail.text = @"test";
```

I also added a label to the detailViewController on the storyboard and then did control/drag to the detailViewController to connect them.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testdetail;
```

Therefore, when I set the text in `prepareForSegue`, I expected it to show in the label once I ran the code on the simulator. However, it didn't show. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you can't update the UILabel before it load...
So what you need to do is this:

Make Nsstring and update it value, then in viewDidLoad update your Label.

In your detailViewController.h add

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *testString;
```

Then in the detailViewController.m in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.testdetail.text = testString;
}
```

in your masterViewController:

```
MMDetailViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
detailVC.testString = @"test";
```

That's it, it should work now :)
Happy coding

Comment: Agreed, except it's usually better to put the code to copy the text to the label in viewWillAppear:animated, so that it displays even if the VC's views have already been loaded (which happens if you keep a VC around and display it again later.)

Comment: "IBOutlet NSString *testString;"  really ?

Comment: @pawan hehehe thanks i didn't saw it, i write the answer from my phone ;)

Comment: No Problem , its just in my habit to catch the wrong things. good answer & explanation .

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil if my answer helped you, you can please vote up :) Thanks and happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

The outlets are accessible after `-viewDidLoad` is fired. That didn't happen yet in `-prepareForSegue:`, so you probably access a label with nil value.

- Ensure that `detailVC.testdetail` is not `nil` in `-prepareForSegue:` first.
- If it's nil, which I assume, the UILabel isn't loaded yet. See **[IBOutlet properties does not update when using prepareForSegue method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033924/iboutlet-properties-does-not-update-when-using-prepareforsegue-method)**

Instead, use a `NSString` property to pass the value around. Put the value into the label in `-viewDidLoad` of your destination `MMDetailViewController` because it's responsible for doing that itself.

Comment: No no no no no! One view controller should not touch another view controller's views. That is a violation of the encapsulation principle of object-oriented design, and a sure path to spaghetti-code. Don't do that. Ever. Instead, add a string property to the destination view controller, set it in prepareForSegue, then add code to the destination VC's viewWillAppear:animated that copies the text from the string property to the view.

Comment: I prefer that, too, yes.