# Data is not being passed to detail view controller in storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

So I know that this question has been answered before, but I feel like my issue is just some small detail I've overlooked. I'm trying to pass data between my view controllers using storyboards, but once I push I'm not getting anything on the other end.

Here's what I have in my seque push method:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailPush"]) {
    NSMutableDictionary *selectedObject = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndexPath];
    PhotoStreamDetailViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
    destController.label.text = selectedObject[kImage][kURL];
}
```

- I have set a breakpoint to ensure that my object isn't 'nil' (there is data prior to passing).
- I created an IBOutlet from the storyboard to the detail view controller

Perhaps there other things that I need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set label text directly from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB.

Create a NSString property in ViewControllerB interface:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *labelText;
```

Then pass this string forward from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB:

```
PhotoStreamDetailViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];

destController.labelText = selectedObject[kImage][kURL];
```

And in ViewControllerB, ie viewDidLoad:

```
label.text = self.labelText;
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So does the newly created string have to be 'strong', 'weak', or ?

Comment: just @property (nonatomic) will make it

Comment: And by default that's 'strong' or 'retain'

Answer (score 2):

Iboutlets are not set when prepareForSegue is called so in your code you're trying to set something that is equal to nil. Create a public property to store your string then set your label in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2):

The IBOutlets won't be set until `viewDidLoad`. You'll want to pass in the data via a publicly exposed `NSString` on your view controller and then set it on `viewDidLoad`.

You can see a more in depth explanation [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033924/iboutlet-properties-does-not-update-when-using-prepareforsegue-method)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
    PhotoStreamDetailViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
    [destController loadView];
    destController.label.text = selectedObject[kImage][kURL];
```

That way you avoid the NSString property to pass the text.