# Strange unwrapping an optional error

Tags: ios, swift

Hi so I have a weird unwrapping optional error that I can not understand slash solve...

I created a new view controller to display meme details, added an image view to hold the memed image, however I kept getting unwrapping a nil error so to test I just added a label, an outlet to the label and then wrote this code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let detailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MemeDetailViewController") as! MemeDetailViewController
    let meme: Meme = appDelegate.memes[indexPath.row]
    print(meme.topText)
    detailViewController.label.text = meme.topText
    //detailViewController.imageView.image = meme.memeImage
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
}
```

The top text for the meme is just TOP, and this is the console output:
TOP
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can someone please help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033924/iboutlet-properties-does-not-update-when-using-prepareforsegue-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the text on the view controller's label before the label outlet has been connected (the label property is still nil)

Add this line of code:

```
print(meme.topText)
_ = detailViewController.view // This forces the view controller to load its view and connect its outlets
detailViewController.label.text = meme.topText
```