# Incompatible pointer type on using segue to pass image? objective c Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, segue

when i trying to use segue to change image on a second viewController, i got a problem which saying:

> Incompatible pointer type assigning to "UIimage*_Nullable" to "NSArray"

and my code is like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"the_segue"]){

   SecondViewController *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

   transferViewController.theimageView.image=@"photo.jpg";
   }
}
```

can anyone help me out for telling me how to solve it , thanks!

Comment: After fixing the string vs image issue you will likely run into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033924/iboutlet-properties-does-not-update-when-using-prepareforsegue-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning theimageView's image property (which is a UIImage) to a string.

I think what you want is `transferViewController.theimageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a String to represent a UIImage in that case the compiler is giving you the warning : "Incompatible pointer type assigning to "UIimage*_Nullable" to "NSArray"

just do:-

```
transferViewController.theimageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"];
```

or

```
[transferViewController.theimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"]];
```

> also you dont need to mention the extention of the image you just mention the name the  extention is need  when there are two image's having similar name but have different extentions.